# Why does posts array only contain one requests worth of data at a time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, request

I'm trying to build an API grabber that requests JSON.

Here is some code:

```
function getPosts(tag, url, callback){
let newUrl = `${url}?tag=${tag}`;

request.get(newUrl, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
    callback(body.posts);
    });
}
```

Array builder function:

```
    buildPostsCollection(options, url, callback){
    let posts = [],
        tagsFinished = 0;

    const permPostsArray = [];

    if(!options || !url){
        return "Error: No options or URL given";
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < options.tags.length; i++){
        getPosts(options.tags[i], url, (posts) => {
            tagsFinished++;
            console.log(tagsFinished);
            permPostsArray.push(posts);
            if(tagsFinished == options.tags.length){
                callback(permPostsArray);
            }
        });
```

If I refresh the page quick enough it alternates between the different tag results.

It's supposed to combine both requests into one array.

Comment: I'm not sure how you *refresh the page*, there is no page afaict.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive on the code. We need to understand your problem in order to answer it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  `buildPostsCollection()` isn't going to call the callback that was passed into it until you have `options.tags.length` items in `permPostsArray`.  So, what exactly is the problem?  There is an issue that you have NO error handling and ignoring any error that `request.get()` might return.